# Android App to send one byte to Arduino board

Tags: android, arduino

I have an example Android app that I compiled in Eclipse and installed on my Android tablet.  It establishes communication between my tablet and my Arduino board.

It is an example program from this link: "Seeeduino Demo - Android App" on this URL:
http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/index.php?title=Seeeduino_ADK_Main_Board

There is a section that simply sends one byte from my tablet to the Arduino board.

```
byte data;
data=1;
server.send(new byte[] {(byte) data});
```

It works, but it sends other bytes besides the one byte.  I need to understand how this server.send() function works, but I can find nothing about it in the Android references.

Can anyone point me to a reference that covers the server.send() function?  I would like to send exactly one byte at a time and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at the source for the MicroBridge.  The following is the working part of the `send` method:

```
    public void send(byte[] data) throws IOException
      {
              try {
                      output.write(data);
                      output.flush();
              } catch (SocketException ex)
              {
                      // Broken socket, disconnect
                      close();
                      server.disconnectClient(this);
              }
      }
```

I would say that there is data in the pipe and is getting writen out with the call to `output.flush()`.

The source for MicroBridge can be found here:  [MicroBridge](http://code.google.com/p/microbridge/source/browse/trunk/src/android/ServoControl/src/org/microbridge/#microbridge/server)

Hopefully this gets you started.